# How can I make a UIPickerView change values when a button is pressed in a cocoa project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

I am running xcode 4.3, and would like to know how to make a UIPickerView change its values whenever a button on the same view is pressed.  Please post some code pertaining on just the changing of the Picker, as I know how to implement it into the button.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your picker is being populated via an Array or similar?

If so then have the button change the contents of the array and then call `[myPickerView reloadAllComponents];`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `UIPickerView`'s `reloadAllComponents` method. So in the button action method, follow these steps:

1. Change the data that is returned by your `UIPickerViewDelegate`. i.e. change whatever object it is you're using within `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` to return the title for that row.
2. Call `reloadAllComponents` on your `UIPickerView`.